# Encountering "error: incompatible types: unexpected return value" and "error: 'void' type not allowed here"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm still very new to Java and I've been stuck on this lab question for my Java course for a while, and I thought everything was good once I got to this point with my code:

```
public class Student {
   // TODO: Build Student class with private fields and methods listed above
   // private variables
   private String name;
   private double gpa;

   // TODO: Define two private member fields
   // default constructor
   public Student() {
      name = "Louie";
      gpa = 1.0;
   }
   
   public Student(String name, double gpa) {
      this.name = name;
      this.gpa = gpa;
   }
    
    public void getName() {
      // TODO: Assign parameter to instance field
      return name;
   }
    
   public void setName(String name) {
      // TODO: Assign parameter to instance field
      this.name = name;
   }
   
   public double getGPA() {
      // TODO: Assign parameter to instance field
      return gpa;
   }
   
   public void setGPA(double gpa) {
      // TODO: Assign parameter to instance field
      this.gpa = gpa;
   }
   
   // TODO: Add three more methods
   
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Student student = new Student();
      System.out.println(student.getName() + "/" + student.getGPA());
      
      student.setName("Felix");
      student.setGPA(3.7);
      System.out.println(student.getName() + "/" + student.getGPA());
   }
}
```

But then I got these errors:

Student.java:21: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
return name;
^
Student.java:44: error: 'void' type not allowed here
System.out.println(student.getName() + "/" + student.getGPA());
^
Student.java:48: error: 'void' type not allowed here
System.out.println(student.getName() + "/" + student.getGPA());

I tried googling the errors to see how others solved these, but I would get rid of one error and encounter a completely different one. I am unsure how to go about solving the "unexpected return value" error. But as for the "void type not allowed here" I tried removing 'void' from the 'public static void main' as I saw that recommended to others encountering the same issue but this caused other errors.

The expected outcome for the code should be something like:
Louie/1.0
Felix/3.7

I am confused as to why the main class is having problems as this part of the code was already filled in when I started the lab.

Comment: `public void getName()` should probably return something other than `void`.

Comment: Compare `getName` and `getGPA`.

Comment: @tkausl I want to have it return the name I assigned as Louie, so do I remove 'void' from the get statements? I'm unsure how to go about this.

Comment: The return type should be `String` instead of `void`. Putting `void` means “nothing is returned”.

Comment: @TimMoore Ok doing this got rid of the errors I mentioned above. Now though I am receiving an error on lines 27 and 37 that is telling me I am missing a return statement. So should I just say 'return name' and 'return gpa' for those two set statements?

Comment: @TimMoore Alright I just went ahead and tried my idea and it finally gave me the expected output! Tysm for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Ordinarily, getters return a value and setters do not. So the return type of `void` for `setName` and `setGPA` would be fine. It’s OK (just unusual and unnecessary) if they _do_ return the value passed to them. It just usually isn’t done, because the caller already “knows” that value.

Answer (score 3):

On line 21 you are returning `name` of type `String` but your `getName()` function's signature is `public void getName()`. To fix this change `void` to `String`: `public String getName()`.